# Codeigniter 3 image upload bug: image filename is incremented, but not updated in the posts table

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

Every post has a main image hence, there is a `post_image` column in the `posts` table.

I have this problem when a post's image is replaced with a *new image*, that has the *same (file)name* as the old one: the image filename is incremented - mypic.jpg becomes mypic1.jpg - but the *filename string* is not updated in the `posts` table.

The code is this and I believe I have identified the source of the problem (commented):

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    //Keep the current image name in the posts table
    //If no new image is loaded
    $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
} else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    // This line is the source of the problem
    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
}
```

I don't know how to increment it properly or even if increment is the best solution.

**The question:** What is the most robust (reliable) way to solve this problem?

---

**EDIT:**

For consistency, I should probably update the initial (when the post is *created*) upload code:

```
if (!$this -> upload -> do_upload()) {
    $errors = array('error' => $this -> upload -> display_errors());
    $post_image = 'default.jpg';
} else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this -> upload -> data());
    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
}
```

Comment: I have added code from my `create()` method. I suppose this should be modified by the same logic (yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This is the check for new file is upload or not
if ( isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'] != null ) 
{
    // Use name field in do_upload method
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))  {
        // If any problem in uploading
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        // This is your new upload file name
        $post_image = $data[ 'raw_name'].$data[ 'file_ext'];
    }
}
else {
    // This is your old file name if user not uploading new file
    $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
}
```

Hope this code will help you to update your file

Answer (score 0):

The upload library automatically increments files of the same name. If you previously uploaded `my-pic.jpg` and then uploaded the same file it would show up as `my-pic1.jpg`. Thus the filename is modified by the upload library.

You have to get the new filename via the function `$this->upload->data()` which returns a bunch of items related to your image upload.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data

You only have to replace `$post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];` with `$this->upload->data('file_name')` or:

```
$file = $this->upload->data();
$post_image = $file['file_name']
```

---

Generally I recommend against using any user supplied name for a file. I would suggest using the `$config['encrypt_name'] = true` to get a randomized name. The above method would apply to this as well.